# IOError: 13, 'Permission denied' when writing to /etc/hosts via Python

Tags: python, io, privileges, sudo, hosts-file

I have a Python app that I'm working on that needs to access the hosts file to append a few lines. Everything worked on my test file, but when I told the program to actually modify my hosts file in /etc/hosts I get IOError 13. From what I understand, my app doesn't have root privileges.

My question is, how can I circumnavigate this issue? Is there a way to prompt the user for their password? Would the process be any different if I was running the app on a Windows machine?

Here's the code in question:

```
f = open("/etc/hosts", "a")
f.write("Hello Hosts File!")
```

Also, I plan on using py2app and py2exe for the final product. Would they handle the root privilege issue for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to write out your changes to a temp file, then run a program to overwrite the protected file.  Like so:

```
with open('/etc/hosts', 'rt') as f:
    s = f.read() + '\n' + '127.0.0.1\t\t\thome_sweet_home\n'
    with open('/tmp/etc_hosts.tmp', 'wt') as outf:
        outf.write(s)

os.system('sudo mv /tmp/etc_hosts.tmp /etc/hosts')
```

When your Python program runs sudo, the sudo program will prompt the user for his/her password.  If you want this to be GUI based you can run a GUI sudo, such as "gksu".

On Windows, the hosts file is buried a couple subdirectories under \Windows.  You can use the same general trick, but Windows doesn't have the sudo command.  Here is a discussion of equivalents:

https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I need. The script is graphical though, so is there any way to pass a string to the system for authentication? I'd like to avoid having the user type into a terminal

Comment: If you run gksu as I suggested, then it will prompt the user in a GUI dialog box.  If you run plain "sudo" then that would prompt in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that for some reason. But, I don't have gksu, do you know what something similar for QT might be?

Comment: I don't, but I just ran a Google search for "QT equivalent to sudo" and I found this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_privilege_authorization_features  Looks like "kdesu" or "kdesudo" might work for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on the `sudoers` list, you can start your progamm with `sudo`:

```
 sudo python append_to_host.py
```

sudo runs your python interpreter with root privileges.
The first time you do it, you will be asked for *your* password, later calls will not ask you if your last `sudo` call is not to long ago.

Being on the sudoers list (in most cases `/etc/sudoers`) says that the admin trusts you. If you call `sudo` you are not asked for the `root` password, but yours. You have to prove that the right user sits at the terminal.

More about `sudo` on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

If you want to remote controll this you can use the `-S` command line switch or use http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I'd like to avoid having to require the user to run the script as sudo. Is there a way to do it for them in the background if I have their password?

Comment: I did some more research on 'sudo -S' and it seems like that's what I can use to pass the user supplied password onto the system. Thanks!