# How to open /etc/hosts file in append mode in Python?

Tags: python, permissions, ioerror

I have one Problem in Python.
I run my python file an in a file I open one .txt file.

`file1 = open("/etc/hosts","a+")`

That Time Got Traceback like this:

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/hosts'`

How can I solve out this Error?

Comment: run as user that access to file or give user access to that file.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOError: 13, 'Permission denied' when writing to /etc/hosts via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510617/ioerror-13-permission-denied-when-writing-to-etc-hosts-via-python)